# Using While and Grep together in Bourne Shell Script

Tags: grep, sh

I'm building a student database in Bourne Shell Script, and this is literally the very first time I've ever even seen code written like this, so I'm terribly out of my element. I need to make it so that when the user inputs a course, the program checks the user input vs a database of courses I already have, and if the course doesn't exist, promps the user to input a new course. This is what I'm trying:

```
   echo "course-1: \c"
   read course1
   while [[ grep -i "$course1" course3.dat == 1]]
   do
        echo "course does not exist"
        echo "course-1: \c"
        read course1  
   done
   echo "course-2: \c"
   read course2
   while [[ grep -i "$course2" course3.dat == 1]]
   do
        echo "course does not exist"
        echo "course-2: \c"
        read course2
   done
```

But I'm getting errors "conditional binary operator expected" and "syntax error near `-i' ". I've been trying to google answers but I'm not coming up with anything useful. So I was wondering if any of you could help me? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[` is a shortcut for `/bin/test`, which isn't what you want. (Here's a [man page](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test) about it.)

Try this instead:

```
while ! grep -i "$course1" course3.dat
```

Or

```
until grep -i "$course1" course3.dat
```

The `grep` expression evaluates to true when grep is successful (i.e. matching lines), and the ! inverts that. Until has built in the opposite semantics from while.

Comment: Yep that works. Thank you. I don't know why I thought I needed [] -.- Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`[[` and `[` are "test", which *is* what you want.

However, different shells have different syntaxes; ksh or bash would interpret "[[" okay, but Bourne shell (normally /bin/sh) would not.